# Why does the head of my ragdoll act like its about to fly off its shoulders?

Tags: unity, 3d, models

The problem can be seen here: https://gfycat.com/LimpingMerryGermanshorthairedpointer

Ive created my ragdolls by using the Unity ragdoll creator tool.

To begin with, all the limbs of my ragdoll acted like this, then I searched online, found this post: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-can-i-prevent-ragdolls-from-stretching-and-spazzing-out.328348/ and enabled projections as advised.

This fixed all limbs but the head.. How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this. The problem was with the collider on the ragdoll head. For some reason it was automatically set to a radius of 0.004, this making it extremely small. I manually increased its size so that it properly covered the head, and this fixed my problem :)